# What is Tidal's 'Master' Quality sample rate and bit depth?

Tags: sample-rate, bit-depth, bitrate, audiophile

I've been using Hi-Fi as my streaming quality, which I believe is 1440kbps and 16bit depth.

Does anyone know where I can find information pertaining to this screenshot?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Fi: 44.1khz/16bit (1411kbps)

Master: 96khz/24bit (4608kbps) [Pitchfork Article](https://pitchfork.com/news/70703-tidal-becomes-first-service-to-offer-master-quality-streaming/)

---

Note that [only ~30,000 tracks are MASTER quality](https://www.whathifi.com/tidalmasters/review) right now

You can tell that Master is available by the M symbol

[image: Master Quality Symbol]

and the playback bar in bottom right will change from HI-FI to MASTER

[image: HIFI]

Answer (score 0):

Master quality releases varies from 16bit/44.1khz (the lowest), and from there up to 24bit/192khz (even 352 khz), being the average "24bit/48khz" and not 24bit/96khz as stated by Tidal.
Important is to note that not all of MQA streaming decoders go up to the higher rates to get the most of them, but being enough for the average audiophile.
Regards
HD